# How can I create a filter with a .ACV file in GPUImage 2?

Tags: ios, swift3, gpuimage

I want to apply a filter that I have created in photoshop to my images, I found examples in GPUImage but I didn't found examples in GPUImage 2 (swift version).

Comment: Maybe they are using the same examples. Try calling the same methods with swift 3 syntax.

Comment: @New16 I can't because in examples it is using GPUImageToneCurveFilter and I think so it is not available in GPUImage 2

Comment: I hope you know how swift works and how you have to write the swift code. This will help in solving the code. You should use `.CurveFilter`.

Comment: @New16 I can't use that filter because I research and found this https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage2/issues/43